# Binding to InnerHTML in MetroStyle App from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a Div Defined as:

```
<div class="article-content" data-win-bind="innerHTML: content"></div>
```

and im binding to it with an object which has content property.

now the object i create using external resources and sometimes the content property would has content like this :

```
"some text <iframe width="560" height="315" src="youtubelink" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```

this throw exception:

```
Unable to add dynamic content. A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously modified dynamically, that might be unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this exception. Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as createElement.
```

I understand the exception and why its happening but now how do i make this work ?

Comment: Do as the error message suggests, if the browser supports it. That would strip out the `<iframe>` element, I fear, so you'll have to rely on some other technique to add content to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "Dynamically adding HTML" section of [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465380.aspx)  You may have to use [execUnsafeLocalFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh767331.aspx) to inject the particular HTML that you're trying to inject.  Also, check out [this blog post](http://gkosev.blogspot.com/2012/08/why-native-development-sucks-and-html5.html) on creating a generic append function that will work in Metro style apps.

Comment: will "execUnsafeLocalFunction "  affect the store app approval?