# How to get JQGrid/JQPlot running on Windows 8

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, windows-8, cordova, jqplot

I currently am developing a phonegap/cordova application.  I have got a iOS and Android build working/running and both utilize JQGrid/JQPlot.  I have updated my jquery code to the win8 version and gotten rid of the pesky exceptions.  However I am now receiving the same unable to add dynamic content exception with the implementation of the JQGrid/JQPlot.  With that said, has anyone been able to find a workaround with either or both of these plugins?

EDIT -

I apologize.. I've been reading about it so much I forgot to include it.

This is the exception.

```
 Unable to add dynamic content '<table><thead><tr class='ui-jqgrid-labels' role='rowheader'><th id='momMeasurementTable_Record' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_Record' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Record<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_Label' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_Label' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Label<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_Date' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_Date' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Date<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_Time' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_Time' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Time<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_MaxCurrent' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_MaxCurrent' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Max Current (A)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_MinCurrent' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_MinCurrent' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Min Current (A)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_MinCurrentLim' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_MinCurrentLim' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Min Current Limit (A)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_Resistance' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_Resistance' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Resistance (mOhm)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_PFUpperLimit' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_PFUpperLimit' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Pass/Fail Upper Limit (mOhm)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_MeasurementTime' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_MeasurementTime' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Measurement Time (ms)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th></tr></thead></table>'. A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously modified dynamically, that might be unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this exception. Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as createElement.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=247104.
```

File: about:blank

Essentially, when the table is being generated the plugin is trying to execute "unsafe code" even though this is a purely local app and the scripting is safe.

That exception shows here in the jquery header.

```
   append: function () {
        return this.domManip(arguments, true, function (elem) {
            if (this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11) {
                this.appendChild(elem); //<-----------------------------
            }
        });
    },
```

I have tried using the `MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(this.appendChild(elem));` and I get a exception saying..

```
Unhandled exception at line 5842, column 21 in ms-appx://664ace5f-4774-4928-bc94-ad4650a1ede1/js/jquery-1.8.2.js
```

0x80070057 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument.

I am not sure where to begin to edit/modify these library files to allow the "unsafe" injection of html/scripts to allow my app to function as it does on iOS/Android.

Any ideas/help would be most appreciated.

Comment: `I am now receiving the same unable to add dynamic content exception` -- nobody is going to know what you are referring to. Do you care to add some specifics to your question?

Comment: I went ahead and updated it, I apologize for not including the exception, when reading various articles I forgot that it isn't self explanatory to everyone.  Would you mind removing the -1 vote if my clarification is sufficent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright for JQGrid.  The key to getting it to work is the following.

In your JQUERY code you need to change...  I got the help from.. [Building a Windows 8 Metro app with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947858/building-a-windows-8-metro-app-with-jquery)  I am leaving the answer here because it should direct those looking for JQGrid/JQPlot questions here as well.

```
append: function () {
            return this.domManip(arguments, true, function (elem) {
                if (this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11) {
                    this.appendChild(elem);
                }
            });
        },        

before: function () {
            if (!isDisconnected(this[0])) {
                return this.domManip(arguments, false, function (elem) {
                    this.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, this);
                });
            }
```

To the following... NOTE ONLY DO THIS IF YOU KNOW THE CODE IS SECURE.

```
 append: function () {
            return this.domManip(arguments, true, function (elem) {
                if (this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11) {
                    var self = this;
                    MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () { self.appendChild(elem) });
                }
            });
        },


      before: function () {
            if (!isDisconnected(this[0])) {
                return this.domManip(arguments, false, function (elem) {
                    var self = this;
                    MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () { self.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, self)});
                });
            }
```

Second note.  I still receive the HTML errors in my log, however it loads properly.  The HTML errors look like..

```
HTML1701: Unable to add dynamic content '<table><thead><tr class='ui-jqgrid-labels' role='rowheader'><th id='momMeasurementTable_Record' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_Record' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Record<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_Label' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_Label' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Label<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_Date' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_Date' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Date<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_Time' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_Time' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Time<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_MaxCurrent' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_MaxCurrent' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Max Current (A)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_MinCurrent' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_MinCurrent' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Min Current (A)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_MinCurrentLim' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_MinCurrentLim' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Min Current Limit (A)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_Resistance' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_Resistance' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Resistance (mOhm)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_PFUpperLimit' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_PFUpperLimit' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Pass/Fail Upper Limit (mOhm)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th><th id='momMeasurementTable_MeasurementTime' role='columnheader' class='ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr'><div id='jqgh_momMeasurementTable_MeasurementTime' class='ui-th-div-ie'>Measurement Time (ms)<span class='s-ico' style='display:none'><span sort='asc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr'></span><span sort='desc' class='ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr'></span></span></div></th></tr></thead></table>'. A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously modified dynamically, that might be unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML property to add script or malformed HTML will generate this exception. Use the toStaticHTML method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly create elements and attributes with a method such as createElement.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=247104.
```

File: about:blank